# Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available' Xcode 14.1 React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native, stripe-payments

Im trying to run my project in Xcode version Xcode: 14.1

(in Xcode 13 is running perfectly)

```
"dependencies": {
...
"react-native": "~0.61.5",
"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.2.2",
...

},
 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.26",
    ...
  },
```

Im getting the following error: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available' in Pods / Stripe ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySzf2.png)

I tried to clean build folder in Xcode, i need a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
@available(iOS 13 ...
```

to

```
@available(iOS 11 ...
```